# Is there best practice for formatting comments?

Tags: python, c++, format, comments

I've been specifically learning Python 3.x and C++14 but anything would be useful.

I'm looking for some literature or guidance on how to format comments, i.e. do you need to leave a specific number of spaces / tabs between code and comment, between comment symbol(s) and comment text, how do you align comments, is it best that they are horizontally aligned if multiple following lines have  comments, or is it better to have them all the same distance from the text that they follow?

I.e. which of these would be "correct":

```
int main() {  //  <comment>
  code  //  <comment>
  much longer piece of code  //  <comment>
  these comments are all over the place //  <comment>

  code                                                                        //  <comment>
  much longer piece of code                                                   //  <comment>
  these comments are aligned                                                  //  <comment>
  but it's unclear which line the comment refers when one line is much longer //  <comment>>
```

Or something else entirely? Or is there no agreed upon best way and it's just about being clear to the reader in which case something like this might be better?

```
int main() {  //  <comment>
  code  //  <comment>
  much longer piece of code  //  <comment>
  these comments are all over the place still //  <comment>

  code  //  <comment>
  much longer piece of code       //  <comment>
  these comments are now aligned  //  <comment>
  and so is this one here         //  <comment>
  but it would be too much to align to this one as the line is so much longer //  <comment>>
```

Comment: The answers for python and c++ are likely to be _very_ different, and depend on whether you are using doxygen, sphinx, or other to generate some doc. As a first approximation, whatever is syntactically valid and seems most readable to you...

Comment: And don't abuse of comment: use correct naming, use functions/classes and you might get rid of most comments.

Comment: This obviously opinion based. But I'd go for consistency with anything already in your codebase, or at the very least consistency in files. Then whatever the required format for auto documentation is, if you're using it. And then whatever you think is most readable. Mini rant - Also be wary of overcommenting. Commenting the why of code where it's not obvious can be okay  and the purpose of unreadable maths. But I personally really hate reading functions that have more comments than code, it's just compensating for awful code usually.

Comment: [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)